# Mini map not showing

Tags: battlefield-4

I have just started playing and am lost because i do not have a mini map. I tried the `B` key however, it does not show. B is the only command bound to it. I have tried rebinding the key and it does not complain about a conflict with another binding.

I can see the map with the `M` key but would like the mini map. How can I fix this?

Comment: Multiplayer or singleplayer?

Comment: Multiplayer online server

Comment: Some servers have the minimap disabled. You can check in the [server overview](http://i.imgur.com/3tdCCF2.png).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some servers, especially those using hardcore mode, can choose to disable the minimap. If the server chooses to hide it, you cannot enable it. You can search for minimap enabled servers using the advanced filters:

[image: Advanced - Show Minimap]

Comment: Yes, for my first match i was on hardcore lol.

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing on a multiplayer server online be sure that the mini-map is activated. There are a number server-side settings which can change the game and the mini-map is one of these. It can be turned off by the server administrator.

In most cases you will find it disabled in the Hardcore preset.